# Browser stacks different versions of style.css

Tags: css, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I am working with a child theme from 'Astra'. I am editing 'style.css' of my child theme for styling my website. I added this code to my child's functions.php' file to enqueue the father-child styles.

```
<?php

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'example_enqueue_styles');

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'astra';

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style ),
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
);
}
```

Although the browser is painting the styles of my child theme as I intend, it also happens to do it twice in different versions of the same code:

[image: snippet of the issue]

It causes styling issues with some elements. I believe the source of the problem is my enqueuing code but I don't know what it is.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid loading style.css twice in child-theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/329875/how-to-avoid-loading-style-css-twice-in-child-theme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from that the parent style is loaded twice :

1. one with version ('?ver=1.0 etc, first on your picture and loaded by your parent theme with versionning on [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) ),
2. another without (the second on your picture, called by your function php).

To solve this : remove

```
wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
```

As it is already loaded by your parent theme and described as a dependency of your child style.

Comment: It'a not the parent theme's stylesheet that's loaded twice. It's the child theme's, because parent themes of use `get_stylesheet_uri()`, which will load the child theme's stylesheet when a child theme is active.

Comment: It has worked fine. Thank you. But it also has changed some styling and had to add a few extra CSS lines. I don't know why that is.

Answer (score -1):

Need to remove this first : add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'example_enqueue_styles');

And, please try this:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

  $parent_style = 'astra'; 
  wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( $parent_style ), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```