# What is the correct way of getting parent styles from child theme?

Tags: theme-development

I just started customising our company's theme. Thus i just started learning wordpress development

In wordpress original [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) about child themes, it says:

> If the parent theme loads its style using a function starting with get_template, such as get_template_directory() and get_template_directory_uri(), the child theme needs to load just the child styles, using the parent’s handle in the dependency parameter.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(),
        array( 'parenthandle' ), 
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version') // this only works if you have Version in the style header
    );
}
```

> If the parent theme loads its style using a function starting with get_stylesheet, such as get_stylesheet_directory() and get_stylesheet_directory_uri(), the child theme needs to load both parent and child stylesheets. Be sure to use the same handle name as the parent does for the parent styles.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parenthandle = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    wp_enqueue_style( $parenthandle, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', 
        array(),  // if the parent theme code has a dependency, copy it to here
        $theme->parent()->get('Version')
    );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(),
        array( $parenthandle ),
        $theme->get('Version') // this only works if you have Version in the style header
    );
}
```

I'm currently using twentytwenty default theme to try customising child themes. I found out that its using `get_template_directory()` thus I went with the first choice. It doesn't work, styles broken. Then I went to the second choice of docs and after that its working.

So what is the correct way to do it? Can anyone explain why is it not working in the first place?

Here's the working code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parenthandle = 'twentytwenty-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    wp_enqueue_style( $parenthandle, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array(),  // if the parent theme code has a dependency, copy it to here
        $theme->parent()->get('Version')
    );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(),
        array( $parenthandle ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version') // this only works if you have Version in the style header
    );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid loading style.css twice in child-theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/329875/how-to-avoid-loading-style-css-twice-in-child-theme)